# How to differentiate token replacement from array index

Tags: 7, tokens

How to escape left square bracket - [ and Right square bracket - ] when used in views so that it is not mistaken for a token.

I have what I hope is a simple question to answer. I have tried searching online but have been unable to find an answer (perhaps using the wrong search terms - I don't know). I am using Drupal 7 with views and the fillPDF module. I have modified one of the outputs of my view to use token replacement. The issue I am having is that the string that is being used for the token replacement has an array with an index that is the same as the token. Here is the code:

```
<a href="/fillpdf?fid=33&webform[nid]=[nid]&webform[sid]=[sid]">Create a PDF</a>
```

As you can see, I need away to make sure webform[nid] and webform[sid] doesn't become webform1 and webform2 after token replacement. How do I accomplish this? There must be a way to escape the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the left square bracket - [ using - %5B
and Right Square Bracket - ] using - %5D

So you should change your code in question to the following.

```
<a href="/fillpdf?fid=33&webform%5Bnid%5D=[nid]&webform%5Bsid%5D=[sid]">Create a PDF</a>
```

Comment: Remember to show the HTML as code.